# How to pass to the last parameter of the route

Tags: php, laravel

I have 3 routes:
1) / catalog / authors and the controller method which simply displays a list of all authors from the database
2) / catalog / authors / {author} a method of the controller that prints out the name of the author if I pass it to id, respectively.
With these 2 I **coped**, but with 3:
3) / catalog / authors / {author} / {book} does not work, problem is that I want to print the first book of the given author (one book of the given author)
Relations between the models are:

Author-Book 1: M

Methods books () and author () respectively.

The route : / catalog / authors / 1/1 Works, BUT on / catalog / authors / 1/2 It produces the exact same result (title of the book for example, as to / catalog / authors / 1/1). Although the author's 2nd book Not specified in the database, tried to explain as clearly as possible.

In general, I do not understand whether there is any query in the database for this check or not.

Routes:

```
Route::get('/catalog/authors', 'AuthorsController@index');
Route::get('/catalog/authors/{author}', 'AuthorsController@show');
Route::get('/catalog/authors/{author}/{book}', 'AuthorsController@display');
```

Controller:

```
class AuthorsController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $authors = Author::all();

        return view('author.index', compact('authors'));

    }

    public function show(Author $author)
    {
        return view('author.show', compact('author'));
    }

    public function display(Author $author, Book $book)
    {

        if (empty($book)) {
            return 'Book doesnt exist';
        }
        return view('author.books', compact('book', 'author'));
    }

}
```

View:

```
{{$book->title}}
```

Models:

```
class Author extends Model
{

    public function books()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Book::class);
    }

}
class Book extends Model
{
    public function author()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Author::class, 'author_id');
    }
}
```

I know i must do something like this:
$bookId = $author->books()->first()->id;

**BUT** i dont know where i must add this: in controller? in route?
how i can transfer this to {book} ?

Comment: what does `{{$book->title}}` in  ur view prints in case of second route `/1/2` ?

Comment: are you following a tutorial here? could maybe reference it for background info. I'm not clear how you don't know if there is a database query? You didn't write this code yourself?

Comment: @jaysingkar same thing like in 1/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your current approach of `display()` method, you are checking if the book with id `$book_id` is present. 
Instead, you should check if the Author has any book with `$book_id`.
So, your `display()` method shlould be,

```
//Check if author has the book with provided book id
$bookResult = $author->books()->where('book_id','=',$book->book_id)->first(); //assuming you have primary key as book_id

if (empty($bookResult)) {
    return 'Book doesnt exist';
}
return view('author.books', compact('bookResult', 'author'));
```